# change available html select options

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a javascript solution to change the available html select options. I have a javascript function being triggered at the right point, but I can't figure out how to change the available options. For example, if option A is selected in htmlselect1, I want the options in htmlselect2 to be updated. Thanks.

What I have seems to almost be working, but it has empty selections in the select options as well. This is the javascript function.

```
function setDurationChoices(){
    var selectedType= hikeTypeID.value;
    if(selectedType=== "G"){
        document.inputForm.duration.options = new Option("3", "5", true);
    }
    else if(selectedType=== "H"){
        document.inputForm.duration.options = new Option("2", "3", "4", true);
    }
    else if(selectedType=== "B"){
        document.inputForm.duration.options = new Option("5", "7", true);
    }
}
```

Here is where it is triggered:

```
<select id="hikeTypeID" name="hikeType" onchange="setDurationChoices()">
   <option value="G">G</option>
   <option value="H">H/option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

Here is the select that I want to dynamically change:

```
<select name="duration">
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: should secondary option be generated dynamically? or it has predefined values?

Comment: Couldn't you just change the innerHTML of the select?

Comment: It initally has some values, yes.

Comment: `document.inputForm.duration.options.innerHTML = "<option value='3'>3</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='true'>true</option>"`...wouldn't that work?

Comment: can you update your question.Put your function option code in to it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what is `new Option`? shouldn't this be a switch statement? where is `hikeTypeId` derived from? there seems to be more to this code than what you are showing...

Comment: hiketypeid is the id of the select that triggers the js function

Comment: new Option was the way I saw it done online in an example

Comment: just put the relevant code in the question.Right now the info provided id insufficient to get any solution.

Comment: @user1154644:you should not use anyhing unless you have some basic info about it.function option is instantiated using the new keyword.
Search about constructor so that you yourself understand the code first.If you dont ,at some point of time you will run in to trouble.

Comment: there must be a function option in your code,append that in the question

Comment: The setDurationChoices() function is there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33455/discussion-between-messiah-and-user1154644)

Answer (score 1):

The optional parameters for Option are the following

```
new Option([text[, value[, defaultSelected[, selected]]]])
```

> text (required) - value shown on page
>
> value - the value
>
> defaultSelected - [true/false] - this is equivilavnt of adding the
>   selected attribute to the element on the html tag. So if you reset a
>   form, the value would remain selected.
>
> selected - [true/false] - selects the value when option is set to true

This creates just a single option element like

```
<option value="G">G</option>
```

To add a option to say hikeTypeId, the code can be like

```
document.getElementById('hikeTypeId').options.add(new Option("g","g",false,false));
```

to flush all previous and add new, it can be done using `[add(element[,index])]` and `remove(index)`

```
while(document.getElementById('hikeTypeId').options.length)
    document.getElementById('hikeTypeId').options.remove(0);

document.getElementById('hikeTypeId').options.add(new Option("g","g",false,false), 0); 
document.getElementById('hikeTypeId').options.add(new Option("h","h",false,false), 1); 
document.getElementById('hikeTypeId').options.add(new Option("i","i",false,true), 2);
```

You can as well use `document.createElement('option')` and set the attributes accordingly, if this is confusing.

```
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.text = text;
option.value = value; 
option.selected = true;
```